# Remove panel from only one workspace in xfce

Tags: xfce, workspaces

I have different workspaces. In one of them I run a virtual machine and I want to remove the xfce panel in that workspace. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Xfce means. You could probably cook up something with wmctrl to set the panel to autohide when you switch to that particular workspace. Xfce forum user ToZ [proposed a script for having per-workspace panels](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8380) a while back which could get you started.